# Does convergence almost everywhere imply convergence in probability in continuous time?

Tags: probability-theory, pointwise-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ a continuous-time stochastic process on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$. Assume $X_\infty := \lim_{t \to \infty} X_t$ exists almost surely. Is it then true that $X_t \to X_\infty$ in probability?

I know that in the discrete case we can argue as following: given $\epsilon>0$, for any $n \in \mathbb N$ the set $A_n := \bigcup_{m \geq n} \{|X_m-X_\infty| \geq \epsilon\}$ is measurable as a countable union of measurable sets; furthermore, $A_n \downarrow \emptyset$ so $\mathbb P(A_n) \to 0$.

But if we index over $[0,\infty)$ instead then clearly this argument does not work, as $A_n$ are not even necessarily measurable any more. We can obviously deduce that $X_{n_k} \to X_{\infty}$ in probability for any sequence $n_k \uparrow \infty$. Is this enough to guarantee that $X_t \to X_\infty$ in probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, for any sequence $(t_k)\subset[0,\infty)$ increasing to $\infty$ you have

$$X_{t_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty} X_\infty \quad \text{$\Bbb P$-a.s.}$$

and hence also

$$X_{t_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty} X_\infty \quad \text{in probability under $\Bbb P$.} \tag{1}$$

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ and

$$a_t(\epsilon):= \Bbb P(|X_t-X_\infty|>\epsilon).$$

Due to (1), we know that

$$ a_{t_k}(\epsilon)=\Bbb P(|X_{t_k}-X_\infty|>\epsilon)\xrightarrow{k\to \infty}0.$$

Since the sequence $(t_k)$ was arbitrary, this means that

$$ \Bbb P(|X_t-X_\infty|>\epsilon)=a_t(\epsilon)\xrightarrow{t\to \infty}0.$$

Since this works for every $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$X_t\xrightarrow{t\to\infty} X_\infty \quad \text{in probability under $\Bbb P$.} $$

---

The main point here is that indeed $X_t\to X_\infty$ in probability if and only if $X_{t_k}\to X_\infty$ in probability for any sequence $(t_k)\subset[0,\infty)$ increasing to $\infty$. The same is true for almost sure convergence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I guess my question is why does $a_{t_k}(\epsilon) \to 0$ for any sequence $t_k \uparrow \infty$ imply $a_t(\epsilon) \to 0$? I understand it intuitively, but how would I show this?

Comment: By definition, $a_t\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}a$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $T\in(0,\infty)$ such that $|a_t-a|<\epsilon$ for all $t>T$. Now, if $a_t$ does **not** converge to $a$, this means that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $T\in(0,\infty)$ there is some $t^*>T$ such that $|a_{t^*}-a|\ge\epsilon$. By induction, you can find a sequence $t_k\uparrow\infty$ such that $|a_{t_k}-a|\ge\epsilon$ for all $k$, so in particular $a_{t_k}$ does not converge to $a$. Using the contraposition, if $a_{t_k}\to a$ for all $t_k\uparrow\infty$, then $a_t\to a$. D'accord?